# how do I get a unique ID per object in Java?

Tags: java

I made a vector set in order to avoid thrashing the GC with iterator allocations and the like 
( you get a new/free each for both the set reference and the set iterator for each traversal of a HashSet's values or keys )

anyway supposedly the `Object.hashCode()` method is a unique id per object. (would fail for a 64 bit version?)

But in any case it is overridable and therefore not guaranteed unique, nor unique per object instance.

If I want to create an "ObjectSet" how do I get a guaranteed unique ID for each instance of an object??

I just found this: which answers it.

[How to get the unique ID of an object which overrides hashCode()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/java-how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode)

Comment: The question is not clear. What exactly you're trying to acheive and why does it need a unique ID per object?

Comment: The description of what you're trying to do is *really* vague. Could you give more information? There may well be a better way of achieving your bigger aim.

Comment: I saw this answer/questin which answers what I wanted.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/java-how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode

Comment: @JonSkeet to create a container which is a set, that will contain exactly one instance of each object that is not a HashMap but relys on a comparable value unique to each object.  And do this without relying on an overridable interface/method such as Comparable<> or hashCode().

Comment: @BjörnPollex right I found the duplicate - it didnt show up on my initial search.

Comment: @peterk: Then `IdentityHashMap` sounds like it's what you're after.

Comment: @JonSkeet  I meant every instance even if hashCode() returns a result that is the same for multiple objects.

Comment: @peterk: Yes, I know. Did you read the documentation for `IdentityHashMap`?

Comment: It should be noted that `System.identityHashCode(Object)` from the selected answer may be not distinct for distinct objects (as already stated in other answers and comments)! https://stackoverflow.com/a/8939049/4130619 seems to be the correct answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`java.lang.System.identityHashCode(obj);` will do this for you, if you really need it and understand the repercussions. It gets the identity hashcode, even if the method to provide the hashcode has been overridden.

Comment: Even if this is already some months old, it should be noted that `System.identityHashCode(Object)` does **not** need to be distinct for distinct objects (as already stated in other answers and comments)!

Comment: Solution given there (with some explanations and details) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/java-how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode

Comment: identityHashCode() returns the result of the hashCode() method defined in Object. in the javadoc for such method it states: "As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)"

Comment: unfortunately this is a bit vague. On a 64bit machine, the virtual address space is potentially larger than an int so, if unlikely, it is possible for two objects to have the same value.

Comment: I've just fallen over this, or rather, one of my users has. Calling identityHashCode() for several million objects, there are about 8 that have duplicate hash codes.

Answer (score 46):

The simplest solution is to add a field to the object. This is the fastest and most efficient solution and avoid any issues of objects failing to be cleaned up.

```
abstract Ided {
    static final AtomicLong NEXT_ID = new AtomicLong(0);
    final long id = NEXT_ID.getAndIncrement();

    public long getId() {
         return id;
    }
}
```

---

If you can't modify the class, you can use an IdentityHashMap like @glowcoder's deleted solution.

```
private static final Map<Object, Long> registry = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Long>();
private static long nextId = 0;

public static long idFor(Object o) {
    Long l = registry.get(o);
    if (l == null)
        registry.put(o, l = nextId++);
    return l;
}

public static void remove(Object o) {
    registry.remove(o);
}
```

Comment: will the code above where you add a field to the object guarantee a unique id per instance created in the face of objects created from multiple threads simultaneously?

Comment: @Geek It will if you use an AtomicLong.

Answer (score 9):

No, that's not how `hashCode()` works. The returned value does not have to be unique. The exact contract is spelled out in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Also,

> supposedly the Object.hashCode() method is a unique id per object

is not true. To quote the documentation:

> As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects.

Comment: I know - that is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to outperform the java GC sounds like premature optimization to me.

The GC is already tuned to handle small short-lived objects. If you have performance issues with GC, you ought to [help the GC](http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html), not re-implement it (IMNSHO)

Comment: I would love it if a realtime deterministic GC was available as a plugin for generic java VMs where I could guarantee the GC would consume more more than 2 milliseconds in each frame of a 60hz simulation loop. Reducing allocations and free reduces the inevitable number of periodic GC stalls.