# ArrayList with returned index on add value

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I am looking for a java data structure similar to an ArrayList that when I do an add or a push with only a value argument an index will be returned for me automatically.

For example:

```
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();

String element = "foo";
String elementTwo = "bar";

int index1 = elements.add(element); //note this does not exist, i.e. returns bool in api
int index2 = elements.add(elementTwo);

System.out.println(elements.get(index1)); //would give "foo"
```

I could see writing a wrapper class around ArrayList that manages a counter that is incremented on every add operation and invoking:

```
ArrayList.add(int index, E element)
```

Do you really need to write a wrapper around ArrayList for this? This seems like something simple enough to be provided out of the box somewhere?

**Edit:**

I need the index (key) to be fixed and unique for this usecase. A map was suggested and I agree with that. Does anyone know of a map implementation that gives you an automatically (uniquely) generated key on a value insert? I am just trying to decide if I need to implement my own wrapper for this.

Comment: `int index1 = elements.add(element).size()-1`; won't that work

Comment: What's wrong with `int index1=elements.size(); elements.add(element);`?

Comment: I'm baffled.  Why is it so bad to write a second line to get the current length???

Comment: Are you always guaranteed to get a unique ID if you use the size? What happens if you delete an element in-between adds?

Comment: @RyanR. I updated my answer to cover this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The element will be added at the end of the list. So you can use `elements.size()-1` to get the new elements index.

Note that this will not work reliable if multiple threads are modifying the list at the same time.

**EDIT:** Also note that it might not be a good idea to use an `ArrayList`s index as a unique ID because an elements index can change (for example when you remove an element or insert a new one using `add(int, Object)`). If this is a problem depends on what you want to do with the index: If you only need it for a short time after adding an element and can be sure that the list is not modified in the meantime, there is no problem. In the other case even a method returning the index when calling `add(Object)` would not help because the index does not get updated in anyway. To prevent this issue you can:

- Make sure you never remove elements from the list and never add elements using `add(int, Object)`.
- Instead of removing elements you could also set them to `null` using the method `set(int, null)`. This way no elements index will change.
- Use some other data structure like for example a map with a custom ID like helloannalil suggests in his answer.

**EDIT 2:** I did not find a appropriate, ready to use implementation (but this does not mean there is none, of course). To suggest a good solution, more information on the intended use of the data structure is needed, but here are some ideas and notes:

- If the maximum number of elements is not to large, an `ArrayList` could be used and the elements index represents the ID. As stated above, to remove an element it can be set to `null` so that no indices are changed. When inserting, positions with `null` values can be reused.
- You can also use one of the two methods show in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8939049/1347968 (keywords `AtomicLong` or `IdentityHashMap`)
- Do **not** depend on the "uniqueness" of `Object.hashCode()` or `System.identityHashCode(Object)` as it is not guaranteed (try it by running the example at the bottom of [Suns/Oracles Bug #6321873](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6321873)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). Going to go with a check on an answer with more details regarding a map implementation or lack thereof.

Comment: @RyanR. I added some implementation ideas and notes…

Comment: I like the research. I ran the HashClash class. Interesting to see uniqueness break there. I don't have 10 billion trials in my system but good to know.

Comment: Going to give you the check (due to background research) though @anubhava had some good input too.

Comment: @RyanR. Thanks :-) I knew the uniqueness is not guaranteed, but I didn't know how "easy" it is to break it… Yes, he has some good points. Without him I wouldn't probably have done this research, so thank you too, anubhava ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well what I do in that cases (I love ArrayLists) is to get the last index by asking the size of the list:

```
String thing = "theThing";
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add(thing);
int indexOfThing = strList.size() - 1;
```

I mean, is easier than implement your own List and just works.

Answer (score 2):

if you really want this function， you can use map but not list

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments and edited question I think you can extend a HashMap for your use like this:

```
public class MyMap<V> extends HashMap<Integer, V> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int add(V elem) {
        int key = System.identityHashCode(elem);
        super.put(key, elem);
        return key;
    }
}
```

Then inside your class declare `MyMap` like this:

```
private MyMap<String> map = new MyMap<String>();
```

And then add your elements to `MyMap` like this:

```
.....
.....
String element = "foo";
String elementTwo = "bar";
int index1 = map.add(element);
int index2 = map.add(elementTwo);
```

Now you have `index1` and `index2` as indices of you inserted strings that you can use or pass around for the lifetime of your application. You can insert or remove elements in `MyMap` as many times you want but your indices (`index1` and `index2`) will give you back your inserted elements like this:

```
String elem1 = map.get(index1); // will return "foo"
String elem2 = map.get(index2); // will return "bar"
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1), this falls under the "implement my own wrapper" part of my question. Will hold off for a bit on the check but will eventually give it to you if no one else can come up with a more 'std library approach'. Curious if this is the most performance wise way to do this? Maybe better to write this kind of thing around a fixed size array if you know you have a bounded set of elements?

Comment: Yes indeed, this falls under the `implement my own wrapper` part of your question. IMO using any array or Collection based implementation will require a lot more code to make it work since you will be adding/removing elements from that storage.

Comment: @RyanR. Please note that this is not guaranteed to work, according to the Javadocs of [`System.identityHashCode(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) and [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) the JVM is not required to return distinct hash codes for distinct objects. The implementation depends on how you want to work with your data structure: How often you add, remove or get elements from it, how many elements there will be in… I'll update my answer later, but it would help if you provided more information… :-)

Comment: @siegi: `Object.hashCode()` can be overridden to return a different value but as per the official Javadoc: `System.identityHashCode(Object)`: Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's class overrides hashCode().` Which means that `System.identityHashCode(Object)` can be reliably used here.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I know, `System.identityHashCode(Object)` always uses the "non overridden" version of `Object.hashCode()`, but `Object.hashCode()` is not guaranteed to return unique hashes, see its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) and Suns/Oracles [Bug #6321873: System.identityHashCode doc inadequate, Object.hashCode default implementation docs mislead](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6321873) (an example demonstrating this is at the bottom of this bug report).

Comment: @anubhava :-D Yes, it is, but it is still relevant, I just tried the example… :-P

Comment: I think this hashCode related discussion is mute. This line: `int key = System.identityHashCode(elem);` can be easily changed to `int key = map.size()+1;` and my suggested code will continue to work.

Comment: @anubhava This doesn't work if elements are also removed from the map: Add element `a` (gets "id" 1), add element `b` (gets "id" 2), remove `a`, add `c` (gets "id" 2). Now `b` and `c` have the same id.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I just overlooked that removal part. So original answer remains there :)

Comment: By using `System.identityHashCode(elem);` as a kye, my Map behaves like [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html). Also check **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/java-how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode** and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938528/how-do-i-get-a-unique-id-per-object-in-java for relevant discussion over its uniqueness.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry to disagree again, but no, it doesn't… It is true that `IdentityHashMap` uses `System.identityHashCode(Object)` to get a "good" hash for the key, but `IdentityHashMap` also handles hash collisions on the key correctly.

Comment: Hope you saw accepted answers of the 2 SO questions about generating unique IDs per object.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, I saw them: The first one states: _Uniqueness isn't necessarily guaranteed, note._ And the second one does not say anything about the uniqueness. And even if an answer is accepted on SO, this does not mean that the answer is correct! But with the example from the link I posted above, you can prove by yourself that `System.identityHashCode(Object)` does **not** provide a unique object ID. It does a good job most of the time (I never questioned this), but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

```
String thing = "theThing";
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add(thing);
int indexOfThing = strList.size() - 1;
```

If you remove an item, this will no longer work.