# Problem with assiging random UUID as a map key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, uuid

I'm making a dispatching (dispatcher?) program. While i managed to create "addReport" method i have issues with displaying all the reports (itering through the map). I think that every time i'm trying to add new elements they are replaced because identificator (UUID) is the same. What do you think, or maybe it is something different?

```
public class Dispatching {
    private String identificator;
    private Map<String, Report> reportMap;

    public Dispatching() {
        this.identificator = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.reportMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    void addReport(String message, ReportType type) {
        reportMap.put(identificator, new Report(type, message, LocalTime.now()));
    }

    void showReports() {
        for (Map.Entry element : reportMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("uuid: " + element.getKey().toString()
                    + " " + element.getValue().toString());
        }
    }

}

public class Report {
    ReportType reportType;
    String reportMessage;
    LocalTime reportTime;


    public Report(ReportType reportType, String reportMessage, LocalTime reportTime) {
        this.reportType = reportType;
        this.reportMessage = reportMessage;
        this.reportTime = reportTime;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Report{" +
                "reportType=" + reportType +
                ", reportMessage='" + reportMessage + '\'' +
                ", reportTime=" + reportTime +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dispatching dispatching = new Dispatching();

        dispatching.addReport("heeeeelp",ReportType.AMBULANCE);
        dispatching.addReport("poliiiice",ReportType.POLICE);
        dispatching.addReport("treeee",ReportType.OTHER);

        dispatching.showReports();

    }



}

public enum ReportType {
    AMBULANCE,
    POLICE,
    FIRE_BRIGADE,
    ACCIDENT,
    OTHER
}
```

Comment: The identificator should be in every Report.

Comment: I agree, i tried that but i don't know how to put this identificator as a key in addReport method. How would you do it?

Comment: `Report report = new Rep...; reportMap.put(report.getId(), report);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are generating the `UUID` only once in the constructor and reusing it inside `addReport` and eventually, map will only keep the last entry for the same key so generate a new ID using

```
void addReport(String message, ReportType type) {
        reportMap.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new Report(type, message, LocalTime.now()));
    }
```

Comment: You are right, i tried it and it worked. But i would prefer if constructor of Report made custom identificator. Unfortunately i have no idea how to put is as a key in addReport method. How would you do it?

Comment: @santana011 There are few ways, either use [static AtomicLong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8939049/4936904) object to generate and use unique IDs or you can create a String ID field in the `Report` class and assign value to it inside constructor using `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` and use it's value as key for your hash map key. You can also [override hash code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) to generate unique id using `LocalTime` field and use it as key

Comment: you can create a String ID field in the Report class and assign value to it inside constructor using UUID.randomUUID().toString() and use it's value as key for your hash map key **<-----this** i dont know how to pass the reference to addReport method. i tried Report.getIdentificator but it doesnt even show up. How to do it?

` **void addReport(String message, ReportType type) {
        reportMap.put(, new Report(type, message, LocalTime.now()));
}**    

`` What do i put here as a key?

PS: Do you know how to make newlines in here? My comments are really messy :/

Comment: @santana011 A) Add field and initialise `class Report{ String ID; public Report(...){ID = } UUID.randomUUID().toString(); // other code...}`. B) use it  `void addReport(String message, ReportType type) {
        Report report = new Report(type, message, LocalTime.now());
        reportMap.put(report.ID, report); // create a getter for ID
    }`

Comment: OH THANK YOU. It worked, i hadnt thought of creating report variable in that method.... Silly me, thanks again.

Comment: I am glad that I could help, Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are right.

```
void addReport(String message, ReportType type) {
    reportMap.put(identificator, new Report(type, message, LocalTime.now()));
}
```

Your *identificator* value is the same for each report you are adding. Hence, it will overwrite the entry in the map.

You must use a different id for each report you add. The choice of this id depends on your use case. Maybe, you can create a UUID each time you insert into the map. Or, you can make each `Report` to have its own id.

It depends.. Should calling `addReport` for the same message and report type create two entries in `reportMap`? If no, then you need to have an id for a `Report`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried something like this: 

`void addReport(String message, ReportType type) {
        reportMap.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), new Report(type, message, LocalTime.now()));
    }
`
And it worked. I think if constructor of Report would generate random UUID's it will be just better. But i dont know how to get that specific identificator to put as a key map in addReport method. How would you do it?