# Wrapper class strange behaviour in java

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 10;
        Integer a = new Integer(i);
        System.out.println(a);        //tostring method overriden
        System.out.println(a.hashCode());
    }
}
```

**Output**:
    10
    10

now my question is why `hashCode()` method is overriden in this case.
If I want to find the object reference of the wrapper class object a in the above code.
How do i do it?

Comment: Maybe that is what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/java-how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode

Comment: What will you do by getting a reference. Just FYI `Integer` objects are immutable in Java. You cannot modify it once they are created.

Answer (score 5):

The object reference to the integer in your case is `a`. Unlike C, in Java, you can't get a reference pointer to an object. The `hashCode` is not used to identify the address location of an object in the memory.

From the [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) API,

> Returns a hash code value for the object. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by HashMap.

As it turns out, the most efficient value of `hashCode` for an integer is the value itself.

If you still want to get hold of the original hash value of the object, I would suggest using the [`System.identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
System.identityHashCode(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

> my question is why hashCode method is overriden in this case

Wrappers, like String, are immutable. Said this, if every different object of a class has a different value (state), that value is a perfect hash code: zero collisions, total entropy, homogeneus distribution...

> If i want to find the object reference of the wrapper class object a
>   in the above code.How do i do it?

Using `System.identityHashCode()`

Answer (score 1):

In Java, hashcode helps to give a quick comparaison hint between two objects. As two different `Integer` having same value are equal, they should have same hash. That's the reason why the value was taken for hash.