# Why hashcode does not generate unique hashcode?

Tags: java, hashcode

We known that default implementation of hashCode() returns integer after converting the internal address [converting the internal address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/java-how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode) of the object into an integer .  So internal memory of every object is different, then **why hashCode() does not generate unique hashcode.**

My question is why  hashcode() [It returns integer which is address representation of an object] does not generate unique code , if we don't override hashcode() and equals?

Comment: The default `equals()` doesn't actually check for full equality either.  To use either you need to override it; if you don't specify a method what do you expect java to do?

Comment: Thanks for your replay But my question is why  hashcode does not generate unique code if we don't override hashcode and equals because it is memory representation of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it can't.

Since there are only 2^32 different ints and there may be more than 2^32 live objects in any VM instance, it is technically impossible to guarantee a unique hash code for each object.

Even if the default hash code may be *based* on the internal address of the object, it is not identical to the internal address.

Comment: "Because it can't." That's not quite true; it can do so for enums. It is just that the contract of the method itself does not require it to do so.

Comment: @fge: Why do you think it's possible for enums?

Comment: @jarnbjo for purely practical reasons; the source of a Java file is limited (I cannot remind the exact limit, but it certainly is less than 2^32 - 1)

Comment: @fge: Yes, there is a limit on the number of different values within one enum type, but the question was not about unique hash codes within one type. And even with one enum type, you can load the type multiple times with different class loaders and obtain more than 2^32 instances of the enum.

Comment: @jarnbjo no you can't; consider that an enum has a `values()` method! It returns an array, whose max capacity is bound by the `int` primitive type -- its positive values, that it: 2^31 - 1

Comment: @fge: And why is it an issue that values() returns an array with at most 2^31-1 entries? Your objections are not making sense.

Comment: @jarnbjo now tell me how a class loader is supposed to handle more than 2^31 - 1 enum values when the `values()` method has to be obeyed?

Comment: @fge: I wrote that you can load the enum type multiple times with different class loaders. Each class loader will give you different instances of each enum value.

Comment: @jarnbjo which doesn't dismiss my comment above; it is perfectly possible for an implementation to guarantee a unique hash code for enum values. For instance, the value of `.ordinal()`!

Comment: @fge: You are obviously incorrectly assuming that an enum value is a singleton, which it is not. If you load the enum type with different class loaders, each value will be its own instance. But I don't know how many times I have to repeat "different class loaders" until you understand that?

Comment: @jarnbjo similarly, you are obviously misguided in the fact that a same classloader can handle realibly more than 2^31-1 enum values, because of the enum constraint themselves. I wonder how many times I have to repeat that until you understand that?

Comment: @fge: Why are the constraints of one class loader relevant when I all the time talk about several class loaders? And even one class loader is not in any way restricted if it loads multiple enum types with a total of more than 2^32 different values.

Comment: @jarnbjo obviously you missed the part where an enum is required a consisten `values()` implementation; this method returns an array, and the maximum number of elements in an array is... 2^31 - 1, which is exactly the maximum allowable range for `.hashCode()`. Do you finally understand?

Comment: @fge: No, but it is not me not understanding. Do you understand the concept of class loaders and that multiple class loaders may load the same type more than once?

Comment: @jarnbjo it will never happen; to user code, when an enum value is asked, there will always be _one_ instance returned, never two. While it is true that the same _class_ may be loaded more than once, spurious instances will be discarded. Now, do you finally understand?

Comment: @fge: No, what you're writing here is simply wrong. If the code runs within different class loaders, the enum values will be represented by different object instances.

Comment: @jarnbjo nevermind, you seem to have been missing my point from the get go

Answer (score 2):

> why hashCode() does not generate unique hashcode

Because it has no obligation to do so...

Quoting the javadoc of [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> It is **not** required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.

And indeed, this is a perfectly legal (even though useless) hashCode implementation:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return 42;
}
```

What *is* required of the `.hashCode()` method is that if two objects are equal according to `.equals()`, then they should have the same result for `.hashCode()`; and the above method fits the bill!

Mind you, in real life, you would never write such a useless hashCode() method as the above...

---

Note about the default implementations, that is the ones of `Object`:

- Its `hashCode()` method calls [`System.identityHashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-);
- Its `equals()` method tests reference equality (that is, for objects `o1` and `o2`, it tests that `o1 == o2`).

If you read the javadoc for `Object` carefully, you will see that the contract for both methods is obeyed; The implementation for it is as minimal as you can get, but the contract is obeyed.

Comment: You should incorporate this important quote from the doc in to your answer. *"This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but **this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language**."*

Comment: @neelabhsingh note that you can only accept one answer; be sure to accept the one which answers your question the best!

Comment: @Radiodef not sure whether this is the really important part here... OP seems to be misguided as to what really binds `hashCode()` to begin with; not to mention that there is no guarantee that the hash code for a "same" object will be the same from JVM run to JVM run

Answer (score 1):

**hashCode only prints the internal memory adress if it is not overridden! (its using the object implementation)**

The hash code for a String object is computed as

```
 s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

Comment: *reply :) replay is something different. dont feel offended by this comment

Answer (score -1):

The hash code of an object is not its memory address. If you need to use a unique integer for an instance, there's a special method for that called `System.identityHashCode(Object)`.

The hash code is just an integer (32 bits) that is meant to give a reasonable approximation of equality. If two hash codes are different, the two objects must be different, but if they are the same they may still be different (though usually they are the same).

This means that if you have two different lists with exactly the same content, they will have the same hash code, but a different memory address.

Comment: `identityHashCode` is not an address, nor does it have to be based on an address, either.