# How to identify an instance of a class for uniqueness

Tags: java, android

I've got a class running on a Android wearable which and there is supposed to be only one instance of it, however I'm very occasionally observing some unexpected behavior which is leading me to speculate if under some circumstances perhaps two instances are being created.

If I was in the C or C++ world I would just add logging statements to the class's methods to log the object's memory address of itself and it would be straightforward to check if there are actually two objects or just one.

What's a Java/Android equivalent way of being able to identify a particular object instance?

Comment: @Blackbelt: No, that's not what's being asked for at all.

Comment: You can use Singleton pattern in order to prevent multiple instances running. If you still insist on tracking objects, you can hash the current time milli second in constructor.

Comment: If your class does not override `hashCode()` (as it sounds like it has no reason to do), then you can reasonably expect that method to return different values for different instances.

Comment: and if it does override `hashCode`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/909861/1864688

Comment: Note, too, that the Singleton pattern cannot be 100% effective in preventing multiple instances.  For one thing, you can have up to one instance *per ClassLoader* with the standard Singleton implementation, and for another, under some circumstances you could obtain multiple instances via serialization.

Comment: I've never used this but have you tried SomeClass.class.getDeclaredClasses() ? Returns an array containing Class objects for all classes, interfaces, enums and annotations that are members of this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default implementation of `toString()` should do the trick. According to the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), it returns `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`, and `hashCode()` should be unique to the instance, unless overridden in such a way that it isn't. According to the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), it seems the default implementation of `hashCode()` uses the object's memory address, offering functionality similar to what you mentioned in C or C++.

If `hashCode()` has been overridden, you could use `System.identityHashCode(Object)` which returns the unique hash code whether or not `hashCode()` has been overridden. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 1):

You could use System.identityHashCode(obj);

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)