# Differentiate string and new string stored in different memory

Tags: java, string

I am new to java, As per my understanding 
`String = "ABC"`  will be stored in string pool and `String s=new String("ABC")` will create a new memory to store the value. if my understanding is correct how to prove this without using `==` or `equals()` method?
Can we prove this using hashcode ? 
I generated the hashcode value for both, it returns the same value... why is that...

Comment: because even though the object in memory is not the same, the value is, and equals will return true. if equals returns true, the hashcode MUST return the same value (unless you are planning to write code that 'll take some additional hours of debugging)

Comment: is there any way to prove this without using equals?

Comment: to prove what, exactly? that the two Objects are equal? you can use the compareTo method

Comment: can you guide me with hashcode

Comment: Why don't you want to prove it with the `==` operator? It's the right one.

Comment: @Ramakrishna you may want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: can you post the code in your project where you find this scenario

Comment: hashCode returns the same value because constructor new String(String original) actually sets hashcode of new instance equal to hashcode of original.

Comment: Have a look at [this question][1] which may help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... how to prove this without using == or equals() method?

The best way<sup>1</sup> to prove it in Java code is to use `==`.

Certainly you can't prove it using `hashcode` on the strings because they will have the same hash code.  To understand why that is, read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--) for `String.hashCode()`.  It explains how the hashcode for a string is calculated.

<sup>1 - You could prove it by comparing the values returned by `System.identityHashCode(Object)`.  However, that's a round-about approach, and the proof relies on knowledge of what the identity hashcode actually means.</sup>

---

> I generated the hashcode value for both, it returns the same value... why is that...

Read the javadoc ... then you will understand.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot prove this using hashcode, because if two strings value are equals it means that they have the same value of hashcode.

You can prove it by comparing their references by using this operator `==`.

Take a look a this [What's the difference between ".equals" and "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and) to understand the exact difference between the `equal` method and the `==` operator.

Comment: Two strings with same values have the same hashcode, and this operator `==` compare the reference of the strings.
Why this explanation is incorrect ?