# How does Object.toString() get the "memory address" and how can I mimic it

Tags: java, memory, tostring

The `toString` method of `Object` is unique in that it seems to be the only place in Java where the memory address is viewable. How does `Object` do this?

I would like to know so that I can mimic its implementation in a class of my own. I can't use `super.toString()` because I'm extending a class which overrides `toString` already.

Update: The premise of my question asks for the memory address, but the answers have indicated that this premise is incorrect, so what I am actually asking is: **How does `Object.toString()` return what it does, and how can I mimic it?**

Comment: Have you tried checking source code of object class

Comment: Obligatory question: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Take a look at the API doc. It’s not the memory address. And there is a way to get the same without using `toString()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode

Comment: System.identityHashCode(Object obj) is used

Comment: @fge for my personal knowledge

Comment: @mmirwaldt, no.  `Object.toString()` uses the actual hash code implementation, not `System.identityHashCode`, and `System.identityHashCode` has nothing to do with the memory address.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860194/what-is-an-internal-address-in-java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not the memory address, it is the `hashCode()`. See also [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) which says (in part)

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@`, and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

And [`Object.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) says *(This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.)* so it's not **required** to be a memory address, and if used it's only visible to the internal (native) implementation of `Object`.

Comment: This answer is the most helpful of the answers, so I am selecting it even though other answers have also been very helpful (such as the fact that I can use `System.identityHashCode`)

Comment: Java is terrible, this is another example of that. The '@' sign is read as 'at', thus if you see `object@f024`, you intuitively think that the object is located **at** that memory address. Using the '@' symbol was a terrible design decision.

Comment: @Jabba What would your proposed alternative default `Object.toString()` use and where would you document it?

Answer (score 11):

> The toString method of Object is unique in that it seems to be the only place in Java where the memory address is viewable. How does Object do this?

It doesn't get the address, in the HotSpot JVM, it gets a randomly generated 31-bit hashcode stored in the header of the object.  This has to be stored because;

- the hashcode cannot change even if the object is moved and has a new address.
- the address is not random enough. The lower 8-bits of the address are always 0. After every GC, the first object to be creates is always the same.
- the address could be 64-bit.

DO TRY THIS AT HOME, NOT SUITABLE FOR WORK!!.

You can get/set the hashCode() using `Unsafe`

```
static final Unsafe UNSAFE;

static {
    try {
        Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
        UNSAFE = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

public static void setIdentityHashCode(Object o, int code) {
    UNSAFE.putInt(o, 1l, code & 0x7FFF_FFF);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Double d = 1.0;
    Double d2 = 1.0;
    setIdentityHashCode(d, 1);
    setIdentityHashCode(d2, 1);
    System.out.println("d: "+d+" System.identityHashCode(d): "+System.identityHashCode(d));
    System.out.println("d2: "+d2+" System.identityHashCode(d2): "+System.identityHashCode(d2));
    System.out.println("d == d2: " + (d == d2));
}
```

prints

```
d: 1.0 System.identityHashCode(d): 1
d2: 1.0 System.identityHashCode(d2): 1
d == d2: false
```

You can get the address from the reference value provided you know how the memory has been translated. In the simplest case, (where you have 64-bit references) the reference is untranslated and the address is the value stored in the reference.

If you run this on a 64-bit JVM with `-XX:-UseCompressedOops`

```
// This only works if a GC doesn't move the object while attempting to access it.
static final Unsafe UNSAFE;

static {
    try {
        Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
        UNSAFE = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

// run with: -ea -XX:-UseCompressedOops
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object i = 0x12345678;
    System.out.printf("indentityHashCode = %08x%n", System.identityHashCode(i));

    Object[] obj = { i };
    assert Unsafe.ARRAY_OBJECT_INDEX_SCALE == 8; // 8 bytes per reference.
    long address = UNSAFE.getLong(obj, (long) Unsafe.ARRAY_OBJECT_BASE_OFFSET);
    System.out.printf("%x%n", address);
    for (int j=0;j<24;j++)
        System.out.printf("%02x ", UNSAFE.getByte(address + j) & 0xFF);
    System.out.println();
    // now some really scary sh!t
    UNSAFE.putLong(i, 8L, UNSAFE.getLong(0L, 8L));
    System.out.printf("`i` is now a %s and is %x%n", i.getClass(), i);
}
```

prints

```
indentityHashCode = 5a07e868
7fbf41cb8560
01 68 e8 07 5a 00 00 00 48 33 3f b9 b9 7f 00 00 78 56 34 12 00 00 00 00 
   ^^hashCode^          ^class address  ^       ^int value^
`i` is now a class java.lang.Long and is 12345678
```

Comment: Don't tell this to people, they'll actually try it :D

Comment: @noctarius added an NSFW warning.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't.  What it gets is the hash code, not the memory address, and the hash code has no necessary connection to the memory address.  (It might in *some* implementations.)

In the base implementation, that's `System.identityHashCode`, though it still has no relationship to the memory address.

Comment: hashCode is a random number in HotSpot (by default)

Comment: So how could I mimic the implementation of `Object.toString()`?

Comment: @4castle the entire implementation is `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`.  That's the whole implementation.  But that has nothing to do with the memory address.

Comment: @Louis Okay, so how do I mimic/get the `hashCode()` if, hypothetically, it had been overwritten by the super class?

Comment: @4castle that's `System.identityHashCode(object)`, but still, that has nothing to do with the memory address.

Answer (score 0):

If you may find the definition of this `toString()` in `Object` Class. You will find this.

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()) //returns classname@hashCode.
```

What it gets is the `hash-code` , not the memory address (As per Louis Wasserman) , and the hash code has no necessary connection to the memory address.

you should override this `toString()` for each class that you declared in your Project as per your Need.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a loophole to get a hold of a memory address because all you get is a randomly generated 31 bit hash-code in the header of the object. It doesn't provide any real way get a hold of a real memory address.