# How to determine if an object is the same one or different

Tags: java, android, object, tostring

I know that `this.toString()` does not print the address of the object but the hash code.  And I have read discussions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376339/how-does-object-tostring-get-the-memory-address-and-how-can-i-mimic-it) as well

**But**, lets say `this.toString()` prints the *same value on 2 occasions* and a *different value on the 3rd occasion*. **Then**, can I conclude that the object on the first 2 occasions was the same and the third occasion was different?

I am trying to determine(*only for testing*) if an object is the same one or a different one. Like say `this` points to same address or different.

Any better ways of checking if an object is the same or different one in Java running on Android devices? *Or if I could get the address of the object in some way then the whole dilemma is resolved.*

Comment: `toString` can be implemented in any possible way, so you'll never be able to get *reliable* information from it in the general sense. If you only care about specific objects with a known `toString()` implementation, then you might get somewhere ... but not in the general case. Also note that getting the address wouldn't even fully solve the problem, because an address could be re-used once the original object was GCed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to determine if an object reference points to the same instance as an other reference is to use `==` operator:

```
yourRef1 == yourRef2
```

Alternatively, if you want to know the immutable reference of an object, you can use `System.identityHashCode(yourObject)`:

> Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned
>   by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's
>   class overrides hashCode(). The hash code for the null reference is
>   zero.

Comment: How do I call this `System.identityHashCode` on a this pointer?

Comment: Simply call System.identityHashCode(yourObject);

Comment: All excellent answers but accepting this answer for the reason that it is the least amount of code required to log the value returned by `System.identityHashCode`, and do a simple check.

Answer (score 4):

There are three main ways to compare two objects in Java:

1. Compare object references (the one you're looking for)

   ```
   obj1 == obj2
   ```

   This condition will be true **if and only if** both references are pointing to **the same object**.

   ```
   CustomType obj1 = new CustomType();
   CustomType obj2 = ob1;
   boolean thisIsTrue = obj1 == obj2;
   ```

   but:

   ```
   CustomType obj1 = new CustomType();
   CustomType obj2 = new CustomType();
   boolean thisIsFalse = obj1 == obj2;
   ```
2. Compare object data

   ```
   obj1.equals(obj2)
   ```

   The result of this condition depends on actual implementation of `equals` method on `obj1`'s class. E.g. this poorly designed `equals` method will always return false. Even if `obj1` and `obj2` are pointing to the same object.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other){
       return false;
   }

   CustomType obj1 = new CustomType();
   CustomType obj2 = ob1;
   boolean thisIsTrue = obj1 == obj2;
   boolean thisIsFalse = obj1.equals(obj2);
   ```
3. Compare object hash-codes

   ```
   obj1.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode()
   ```

   The result of this condition depends on actual implementation of `hashCode` method on both `obj1`'s and `obj2`'s classes. Using this approach is not encouraged as it is even less trustable. Two completely different objects can have the same hash-code. It should be used providently and cautiously in some specific cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the equality of message you should use `equals` method available in object class, which is super class to all classes in Java by default.

Let's you want to check for Object `Mapper`. You can do it like below:

```
Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
Mapper mapper1 = mapper;
Mapper mapper2 = new Mapper();
mapper.equals(mapper1); //true
mapper.equals(mapper2); //false
```

There can be two objects with same `hashcode` with still they can be different. If you want some custom equal checking logic, then you should override `hashcode` and `equals` method of `Object` class in your Class.