# Comparator suitable for TreeSet when there is no distinguishing field

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

Suppose I have a class not implementing the `Comparable` interface like

```
class Dummy {
}
```

and a collection of instances of this class plus some function external to the class that allows comparing these instances partially (a map will be used for this purpose below):

```
Collection<Dummy> col = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Dummy, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    Dummy d = new Dummy();
    col.add(d);
    map.put(d, i % 4);
}
```

Now I want to sort this collection using the `TreeSet` class with a custom comparator:

```
TreeSet<Dummy> sorted = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Dummy>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Dummy o1, Dummy o2) {
        return map.get(o1) - map.get(o2);
    }
});
sorted.addAll(col);
```

The result is obviously unsatisfactory (contains less elements than the initial collection). This is because such a comparator **is not consistent with `equals`**, i.e. sometimes returns `0` for non-equal elements. My next attempt was to change the `compare` method of the comparator to

```
@Override
public int compare(Dummy o1, Dummy o2) {
    int d = map.get(o1) - map.get(o2);
    if (d != 0)
        return d;
    if (o1.equals(o2))
        return 0;
    return 1; // is this acceptable?
}
```

It seemingly gives the desired result for this simple demonstrational example but I'm still in doubt: is it correct to always return `1` for unequal (but undistinguishable by the map) objects? Such a relation still violates the general contact for the `Comparator.compare()` method because `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` is, generally, wrong. Do I really need to implement a correct total ordering for `TreeSet` to work correctly or the above is enough? How to do this when an instance has no fields to compare?

For more real-life example imagine that, instead of `Dummy`, you have a type parameter `T` of some generic class. `T` may have some fields and implement the `equals()` method through them, but you don't know these fields and yet need to sort instances of this class according to some external function. Is this possible with the help of `TreeSet`?

#### Edit

Using `System.identityHashCode()` is a great idea but there is (not so small) chance of **collision**.

Besides possibility of such a collision, there is one more **pitfall**. Suppose you have 3 objects: `a`, `b`, `c` such that `map.get(a) = map.get(b) = map.get(c)` (here `=` isn't assignment but the mathematical equality), `identityHashCode(a) < identityHashCode(b) < identityHashCode(c)`, `a.equals(c)` is true, but `a.equals(b)` (and hence `c.equals(b)`) is false. After adding these 3 elements to a `TreeSet` in this order: `a, b, c` you can get into a situation when all of them have been added to the set, that contradicts the prescribed behaviour of the `Set` interface - it should not contain equal elements. How to deal with that?

In addition, it would be great if someone familiar with `TreeSet` mechanics explained to me what does the term *"well-defined"* in the phrase *"The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals"* from [TreeSet javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) mean.

Comment: A TreeSet works by keeping elements in a strict order.  If you don't tell it how to order the elements, how can you expect it to be able to find them?  Would you be able to find a book in a library where items are just placed randomly on shelves?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Is the above comparator enough if the only thing that I need from TreeSet is to **sort** elements at the time of its creation and output the result as a list? I don't need extended possibilities like `tailSet()`.

Comment: No, it really isn't.  If your comparator doesn't work the way it should, your map won't work the way it should.

Comment: The example you give for a comparator seems fairly arbitrary. If it really is arbitrary you may be better off using a LinkedHashSet (so that the order of insertions is maintained for iteration purposes)

Comment: Please give a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @RoyShahaf The question is specifically about `TreeSet`. It should sort the items according to some given function (consider it to be arbitrary [ToIntFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) instead of `map.get()` in the example). Insertion order (that `LinkedHashSet` uses) may be inconsistent with results of this function.

Comment: Then you should modify Dummy so that equals and hashCode use ToIntFunction (if compare(dummy1, dummy2) == 0, equals should return true, and hashCode should be the same)

Comment: @RoyShahaf No, `Dummy` is a black box in this example, I cannot change it (see the paragraph about `T` parameter of generic class).

Comment: can you modify the map? if each dummy is mapped to a pair made of an int and a uuid you can guarantee uniqueness in a more reliable way

Comment: @RoyShahaf No, it is not possible. The `map` just implements `ToIntFunction` for the example, it is a black box too. The only thing that I can change is the comparator I use when creating the `TreeSet`. Look at the example of solution that JB Nizet has given.

Comment: Well, I would recommend taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909843/how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-an-object-which-overrides-hashcode, then.

Comment: To distinguish between "logically equal" but different objects in a TreeSet, I'd suggest using Guava's [Ordering.arbitrary()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary--).

Comment: Regarding your paragraph "one more pitfall" this is a consequence of the comparator being inconsistent with equals. That is, you may have two elements *a* and *b* in a SortedSet such that compare(a, b) != 0 but a.equals(b) is true. Thus, as you observe, this set violates the Set invariant that there are no two elements such that a.equals(b) is true. SortedSet replaces this with the invariant that there are no two elements such that compare(a, b) == 0. (You have to read between the lines of the docs to understand this.)

Comment: Are you sure the scenario you're suggesting in your edit is possible? The documentation for Object.hashCode requires that two objects that are equivalent via Object.equals must also return the same integer from Object.hashCode. System.identityHashCode "Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's class overrides hashCode()." So a.equals(c) == true implies System.identityHashCode(a) == System.identityHashCode(c). and so identityHashCode(a) < identityHashCode(b) < identityHashCode(c) can't be true

Comment: @heisbrandon "So a.equals(c) == true implies System.identityHashCode(a) == System.identityHashCode(c)." No, `a.equals(c) == true` implies `a.hashCode() == c.hashCode()` only. So the scenario is quite possible when `hashCode()` has been overridden (and thus differs from `System.identityHashCode()`).

Comment: @JohnMcClane if you haven't overriden equals then System.identityHashCode will return the same value for equal objects regardless of the implementation of hashCode.

Comment: @heisbrandon I haven't overridden `equals` and `hashCode` in the `Dummy` class for the sake of simplicity only. I'm still looking for a more or less general solution (look at the paragraph *For more real-life example imagine that...*) You may assume that `hashCode` is consistent with `equals` (whether both are overridden or not), as in the [general contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) of `hashCode` in JavaDoc.

Comment: Sorry @JohnMcClane, I missed that part of your question but I suppose it would have made the most sense to assume that's the case. Is there any reason a TreeSet is absolutely necessary? Seems like you could use an ArrayList and call Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c).

Comment: @heisbrandon I mean that you **can rely on** general contract of `hashCode` when answering this question. I stick to `TreeSet` because it combines sorting capabilities with set capabilities (those that lists cannot provide). Besides that, I need an additional explanation of `TreeSet` general contract (I added a paragraph to question to clarify this).

Comment: @StuartMarks Sorry for late reply. I looked at the Guava's `Ordering.arbitrary()` and found the phrase in its javadoc that unequivocally cautions against using it in `SortedSet`. In particular, there may be the case when I happen to add two equal (by `equals()`) but not identically equal (by `x == y`) objects to a set and I expect the second to be rejected from adding. In other words, I expect the comparator to be **consistent** with `equals()` (which is given, as well as `hashCode()` consistent with it, may be used in your implementation but cannot be changed).

Comment: @JohnMcClane Right, the phrase that cautions against use of `Ordering.arbitrary` for a `SortedSet` is the same caution about using a comparator that's inconsistent with equals. Essentially `SortedSet` changes the semantics of set membership to follow the comparator instead of the equals() method. This is fine if your application can deal with that. But if you're mixing regular Sets and SortedSets, you can get unexpected behavior, depending on whose set-membership test is being used. I guess I should type in a full answer....

Comment: @StuartMarks I think it doesn't change the semantics. `TreeSet` is still a `Set` but uses comparator for its functioning. That's why the stipulation was made in javadoc that comparator should be consistent with `equals()`. I understand that if this is not the case, then `TreeSet` is not a `Set` but still curious whether it can be used just for sorting unequal elements with such an 'incomplete' comparator. That was the 2nd part of my question. The 1st (and more important) one was a request for a 'good' (i.e. consistent with `equals()`) comparator in circumstances when no fields are accessible.

Comment: By "semantics" I mean how the different sets determine whether elements are duplicates. A `Set` considers elements duplicates when `equals` returns true. A `SortedSet` considers elements duplicates when `compare` returns 0. In general, they have different semantics. A `SortedSet` *can have* the same semantics as a `Set` if its comparison method is consistent with equals. But a `SortedSet` *need not have* the same semantics as a `Set` in order to behave usefully; this is the case if its comparison method is inconsistent with equals.

Comment: I started on an answer to this question but I found myself quite confused by the multiple edits and your explanations of the questions in this series of comments. Maybe you should consider asking one or more new questions. One might focus on the actual problem you're trying to solve. Another might focus on the finer points of comparators and consistency with equals for SortedSets. Having all this bound up in a single question is really confusing.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added an answer anyway, but it might not be the one you're looking for.

Comment: One easy option is to use one of the other sortable collections that does support multiple equal elements.  For example, a list is easy to sort using Collections.sort(), and then items will be ordered as specified with equal elements next to each-other in no specific order.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you have an absolutely huge amount of Dummy objects and really bad luck, you can use `System.identityHashCode()`to break ties:

```
Comparator.<Dummy>comparingInt(d -> map.get(d))
          .thenComparingInt(System::identityHashCode)
```

Your comparator is not acceptable, since it violates the contract: you have d1 > d2 and d2 > d1 at the same time if they're not equal and don't share the same value in the map.

Comment: Thanks @John, fixed.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but I'd be wary of relying on uniqueness of identityHashCode. It's decidedly not unique. It's possible to get duplicate values after creating around 100,000 objects.

Comment: @StuartMarks This is very important remark, thank you. I've tried to create a bunch of `Dummy` objects adding them to a list (to avoid them to be garbage collected) and adding their `identityHashCode`s to a set simultaneously. And already on the 105842-nd `Dummy` I've got a repeating hashCode. So this answer needs to be improved.

Comment: I have edited the question, please look at the added paragraph.

Comment: If you need to cope with the case when you have a collision in `System::identityHashCode`, you will need to arbitrarily break those ties (e.g. by the order the items appear in the input collection) and remember those decisions. Something like 1) map the input collection into a List using the above  `Comparator`, then 2) create a new Comparator for the TreeSet based on `List.indexOf` from that list (or compute a map for more efficiency).

Answer (score 3):

This answer covers just the first example in the question. The remainder of the question, and the various edits, are I think better answered as part of separate, focused questions.

The first example sets up 12 instances of `Dummy`, creates a map that maps each instance to an `Integer` in the range [0, 3], and then adds the 12 `Dummy` instances to a `TreeSet`. That `TreeSet` is provided with a comparator that uses the Dummy-to-Integer map. The result is that the `TreeSet` contains only four of the `Dummy` instances. The example concludes with the following statement:

> The result is obviously unsatisfactory (contains less elements than the initial collection). This is because such a comparator is not consistent with equals, i.e. sometimes returns 0 for non-equal elements.

This last sentence is incorrect. The result contains fewer elements than were inserted because the comparator considers many of the instances to be duplicates and therefore they aren't inserted into the set. The `equals` method doesn't enter the discussion at all. Therefore, the concept of "consistent with equals" isn't relevant to this discussion. `TreeSet` never calls `equals`. The comparator is the only thing that determines membership in the `TreeSet`.

This seems like an unsatisfactory result, but only because we happen "know" that there are 12 distinct `Dummy` instances. However, the `TreeSet` doesn't "know" that they are distinct. It only knows how to compare the `Dummy` instances using the comparator. When it does so, it finds that several are duplicates. That is, the comparator returns 0 sometimes even though it's being called with `Dummy` instances that we believe to be distinct. That's why only four `Dummy` instances end up in the `TreeSet`.

I'm not entirely sure what the desired outcome is, but it seems like the result `TreeSet` should contain all 12 instances ordered by values in the Dummy-to-Integer map. My suggestion was to use Guava's [`Ordering.arbitrary()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary--) which provides a comparator that distinguishes between distinct-but-otherwise-equal elements, but does so in a way that satisfies the general contract of Comparator. If you create the `TreeSet` like this:

```
SortedSet<Dummy> sorted = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.<Dummy>comparingInt(map::get)
                                                  .thenComparing(Ordering.arbitrary()));
```

the result will be that the `TreeSet` contains all 12 `Dummy` instances, sorted by `Integer` value in the map, and with `Dummy` instances that map to the same value ordered arbitrarily.

In the comments, you stated that the `Ordering.arbitrary` doc "unequivocally cautions against using it in `SortedSet`". That's not quite right; that doc says,

> Because the ordering is identity-based, it is not "consistent with Object.equals(Object)" as defined by Comparator. Use caution when building a SortedSet or SortedMap from it, as the resulting collection will not behave exactly according to spec.

The phrase "not behave exactly according to spec" really means that it will behave "strangely" as described in the class doc of [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html):

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be *consistent with equals* if and only if `c.compare(e1, e2)==0` has the same boolean value as `e1.equals(e2)` for every e1 and e2 in S.
>
> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of `equals`.
>
> For example, suppose one adds two elements a and b such that `(a.equals(b) && c.compare(a, b) != 0)` to an empty TreeSet with comparator c. The second add operation will return true (and the size of the tree set will increase) because a and b are not equivalent from the tree set's perspective, even though this is contrary to the specification of the Set.add method.

You seemed to indicate that this "strange" behavior was unacceptable, in that `Dummy` elements that are `equals` shouldn't appear in the `TreeSet`. But the `Dummy` class doesn't override `equals`, so it seems like there's an additional requirement lurking behind here.

There are some additional questions added in later edits to the question, but as I mentioned above, I think these are better handled as separate question(s).

**UPDATE 2018-12-22**

After rereading the question edits and comments, I think I've finally figured out what you're looking for. You want a comparator over any object that provides a primary ordering based on some int-valued function that may result in duplicate values for unequal objects (as determined by the objects' `equals` method). Therefore, a secondary ordering is required that provides a total ordering over all unequal objects, but which returns zero for objects that are `equals`. This implies that the comparator should be consistent with equals.

Guava's `Ordering.arbitrary` comes close in that it provides an arbitrary total ordering over any objects, but it only returns zero for objects that are identical (that is, `==`) but not for objects that are `equals`. It's thus inconsistent with equals.

It sounds, then, that you want a comparator that provides an arbitrary ordering over unequal objects. Here's a function that creates one:

```
static Comparator<Object> arbitraryUnequal() {
    Map<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    return (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(map.computeIfAbsent(o1, x -> map.size()),
                                       map.computeIfAbsent(o2, x -> map.size()));
}
```

Essentially, this assigns a sequence number to every newly seen unequal object and keeps these numbers in a map held by the comparator. It uses the map's size as the counter. Since objects are never removed from this map, the size and thus the sequence number always increases.

(If you intend for this comparator to be used concurrently, e.g., in a parallel sort, the `HashMap` should be replaced with a `ConcurrentHashMap` and the size trick should be modified to use an `AtomicInteger` that's incremented when new entries are added.)

Note that the map in this comparator builds up entries for every unequal object that it's ever seen. If this is attached to a `TreeSet`, objects will persist in the comparator's map even after they've been removed from the `TreeSet`. This is necessary so that if objects are added or removed, they'll retain consistent ordering over time. Guava's `Ordering.arbitrary` uses weak references to allow objects to be collected if they're no longer used. We can't do that, because we need to preserve the ordering of non-identical but equal objects.

You'd use it like this:

```
SortedSet<Dummy> sorted = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.<Dummy>comparingInt(map::get)
                                                  .thenComparing(arbitraryUnequal()));
```

---

You had also asked what "well-defined" means in the following:

> The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals

Suppose you were to use a `TreeSet` using a comparator that's inconsistent with equals, such as the one using Guava's `Ordering.arbitrary` shown above. The `TreeSet` will still work as expected, consistent with itself. That is, it will maintain objects in a total ordering, it will not contain any two objects for which the comparator returns zero, and all its methods will work as specified. However, it is possible for there to be an object for which `contains` returns true (since that's computed using the comparator) but for which `equals` is false if called with the object actually in the set.

For example, `BigDecimal` is `Comparable` but its comparison method is inconsistent with equals:

```
> BigDecimal z = new BigDecimal("0.0")
> BigDecimal zz = new BigDecimal("0.00")
> z.compareTo(zz)
0
> z.equals(zz)
false
> TreeSet<BigDecimal> ts = new TreeSet<>()
> ts.add(z)
> HashSet<BigDecimal> hs = new HashSet<>(ts)
> hs.equals(ts)
true
> ts.contains(zz)
true
> hs.contains(zz)
false
```

This is what the spec means when it says things can behave "strangely". We have two sets that are equal. Yet they report different results for `contains` of the same object, and the `TreeSet` reports that it contains an object even though that object is unequal to an object in the set.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it resolves the collision issue with JB Nizet's answer but is still incomplete. Please pay attention to the word *like* at the very beginning of the question. Do you really think that I had to sort 12 instances of such a simple class and disturbed the community with such a simple question, having chosen the reason "Question is widely applicable to a large audience" for the bounty? The paragraph *For more real-life example imagine that...* has existed from the outset. It explicitly (no "lurking behind") stipulates the possibility of the overridden `equals()` method.

Comment: The requirement for the comparator is simple: it should be consistent with `equals()` (whether the latter is overridden or not) and distinguish elements that the initial comparator (`map::get` in your example) does not distinguish.

Comment: @JohnMcClane Of course, the `Dummy` class is example code; everybody (including me) realizes that. What's difficult is that you're asking for a comparator that's consistent with equals, but you haven't described of what that `equals` method might do. It seems like `equals` might look at some fields not known to the comparator, yet you're requiring that the comparator distinguish objects (and provide a total ordering) based on those unknown fields. Seems impossible to me. Or, perhaps I'm still misunderstanding something.

Comment: I'm not showing fields of the class instances of which are supposed to be sorted not due to secrecy of these fields but because I don't have them! I'm trying to sort type (`T`) instances of a generic class. The problem you described is common to generic classes: you have `GenericClass<T extends Bound>` and trying to make the most of it, but the only fields and methods that you can use when referring to `T` are those present in `Bound`. In my case, `Bound = Object`, so you have only methods from `Object` at your disposal.

Comment: It is not a little, though. You have the method `equals()` itself. And don't forget about `hashCode()` which (as opposed to hapless `identityHashCode()`) you can assume to be consistent with `equals()`.

Comment: @JohnMcClane OK I think we're making a bit of progress. You're trying to sort some objects on some first-level classification, which in your example is embodied by the Dummy-to-Integer map. There are going to be a bunch of unequal objects that all have the same value in this first level of sorting, so clearly there needs to be additional criteria. Do you care about these criteria, or can they be arbitrary? (Other than the criteria being consistent with equals.)

Comment: @JohnMcClane It also occurs to me that we're fixated on `SortedSet` which requires a well-behaved comparator. Would it work to maintain the elements in a list and then just sort them according to the first-level classification? Sorting is stable, so the relative order among first-level-equivalent objects will be preserved.

Comment: I realize that if I had to keep the insertion order then probably the best solution would be: 1. Add all elements to a `LinkedHashSet` to remove duplicates; 2. Write out all of them to a `List`; 3. Sort it with the partial comparator (`map::get`). But I need specifically the `SortedSet` as the output and the essence of the question is to create as little overhead as possible. Remember, each additional set takes memory about 10 times as an array holding the same collection. As for the additional requirements, they are (in this order): 1. Performance; 2. Less memory overhead.

Comment: Why are you using `Integer.compare` in `arbitraryUnequal()` instead of simple difference? It seems redundant in your case because `map.size()` is never negative.

Comment: @JohnMcClane Mostly habit. `Integer.compare` is never incorrect. Subtraction is sometimes incorrect and must be proven correct based on context. Context can change with maintenance, introducing risk of errors.

Comment: Thank you for the addition to your answer, I learned many useful things from it, though I recommend to resort to map-based tie resolution only at the final stage, as I did at my answer, because keeping a map that covers all elements of the set may be memory consuming and retrieving its values may be time consuming as compared with `hashCode()`.

Comment: @JohnMcClane Great, glad to be of help. And yes, the intermediate ordering based on hashCode seems like a useful optimization. Thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the comparator I ended up with. It is both reliable and memory efficient.

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> uniqualizer() {
    return new Comparator<T>() {
        private final Map<T, Integer> extraId = new HashMap<>();
        private int id;

        @Override
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            int d = Integer.compare(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());
            if (d != 0)
                return d;
            if (o1.equals(o2))
                return 0;
            d = extraId.computeIfAbsent(o1, key -> id++)
              - extraId.computeIfAbsent(o2, key -> id++);
            assert id > 0 : "ID overflow";
            assert d != 0 : "Concurrent modification";
            return d;
        }
    };
}
```

It creates total ordering on all objects of the given class `T` and thus allows to distinguish objects not distinguishable by a given comparator via attaching to it like this:

```
Comparator<T> partial = ...
Comparator<T> total = partial.thenComparing(uniqualizer());
```

In the example given at the question, `T` is `Dummy` and

```
partial = Comparator.<Dummy>comparingInt(map::get);
```

Note that you don't need to specify the type `T` when calling `uniqualizer()`, complier automatically determines it via type inference. You only have to make sure that `hashCode()` in `T` is consistent with `equals()`, as described in the [general contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) of `hashCode()`. Then `uniqualizer()` will give you the comparator (`total`) consistent with `equals()` and you can use it in any code that requires comparing objects of type `T`, e.g. when creating a `TreeSet`:

```
TreeSet<T> sorted = new TreeSet<>(total);
```

or sorting a list:

```
List<T> list = ...
Collections.sort(list, total);
```

Comment: What do you achieve with this?  What problem do you solve?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I had to create `SortedSet` of objects of a generic type and the initial comparator (which I intended to use as a parameter to constructor of `TreeSet`) wasn't sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: How does it make sense to sort a generic type?  I am trying to understand why you were forced to basically create a sort key on the fly.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That was done to make `TreeSet` work as a normal set, i.e. to accept distinct (by `equals()`) and discard repeating elements, to give expected results of `contains()` etc., while using its sorting capabilities at the same time. The initial sorting criteria was suitable for a list, but not for a set. The key point here is that the sorting criteria was **external**, i.e. not determined by the input objects' fields themselves.